# How can Linkedin access my account without asking for my password?

Tags: passwords

A few days ago, I contacted LinkedIn support for an unrelated issue.

They didn't provide any help with the issue at hand and instead responded with this :

> Do we have your permission to log in to your account and where necessary, take action on your behalf to address the specific issue you are reporting? If yes, we won't require any additional details (including your password) to securely access your account.

I refused (because the issue was unrelated to my account), and I got one more message insisting :

> Please rest assured that your privacy and security are of utmost importance to us. To clarify, we will not require your password or any sensitive information to securely access your account.
> Your cooperation in granting us permission to access your account will significantly expedite the resolution process. Once granted access, our team will work diligently to investigate and address the specific issue you've reported.

**I don't understand how they can access my account without my password. Are they storing passwords in plain text ??**

I can't believe such a big company is making such a rookie mistake, and it must be something else.

I questioned them about it, but my ticket was closed without any response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't need the password to change anything on your account. They own every single bit of information about you. To change your email, for instance, they just edit the email on your record, and that's it.

You are a user, so you need to use the "user endpoint," while the support uses the "support endpoint" and has access to everything on every account. That's by definition: they are "superusers" and must have the power to change anything anywhere, anytime. The support people will not abuse this power because their access is monitored and logged.

I believe your ticket got closed because if you weren't granted permission to address the issue, there's nothing they were authorized to do, so there was no point wasting any time on your ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In my specific case, the issue of the ticket is visible from my public profile. If so, why would they ask me to access my record ?

Comment: To comply with internal rules: support changed something in your public profile according to the authorization you gave.

Comment: Even without _changing_ anything, company employees (especially including support staff) generally need permission to even look at another user's profile from their work machines, because there have been a lot of nasty cases of people abusing internal access to view accounts they shouldn't. In your cases, they maybe could have opened a private browser window and viewed the public profile, but they likely wouldn't have had the tools to diagnose the issue, much less do anything about it, without being logged into their support accounts.